# Error al tratar de instalar el paquete "Rstan"

Tags: rstudio, packages

estoy tratando de instalar el paquete "Rstan" pero me sale el siguiente error:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstan’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required

No se muy bien a que se refiere con las versiones que tengo y la que me requiere y como solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias ¡!

Comment: Parece que se refiere a que necesitas el cli al menos en versión 3.4.0, creo que se refiere al [cli](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cli/index.html)